# Cartesian product of two tables: Oracle Sql Join On True

Tags: sql, oracle, join, cartesian-product

I want to concatenate _BAR to the results of a Query.

One of my first attempts is this:

```
SELECT lhs.f||rhs.f as concat_bar FROM (
SELECT 'FOO' as f FROM DUAL) lhs 
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT '_BAR' as f FROM DUAL) rhs
ON ('' != rhs.f) 
;
```

but I got no results. I was expecting `ON ('' != rhs.f)` to evaluate to `true` so I expected as a result a single row: `'FOO_BAR'`. Which is the result of concatenating the cartesian product of the lhs and rhs tables.

How can I `JOIN on TRUE`?

I know that, for the specific problem, other solutions as

```
SELECT lhs.f||'_BAR' FROM (
SELECT 'FOO' as f FROM DUAL) lhs;
```

are possible.

My question is on an effective syntax to make a cartesian product of two tables as a `LEFT JOIN ON TRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the issues with `null`, is a cross join what you wanted?

```
select lhs.f || rhs.f as concat_bar
from   ( select 'FOO' as f from dual ) lhs
       cross join
       ( select '_BAR' as f from dual ) rhs
```

Comment: Yes, my question is about it. Thx. The issue with null was accidental.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle (by default) treats an empty string as `NULL`.  This is a real pain.  It is different from other databases.  I suppose their argument is:  "Well, we were doing it for years before ANSI defined `NULL` values."  Great, but those years were the 1980s.

In any case, this logic:

```
'' <> rhs.f
```

(`<>` is the original not-equals operator in SQL.)

is exactly the same as:

```
NULL <> rhs.f
```

This always returns `NULL` and that is treated as not-true in `WHERE` conditions.

In Oracle, express this emptiness as:

```
rhs.f is not null
```